# Jenkins JaCoCo code report plugin is not executed if Build failed

Tags: jenkins, jacoco

I'm facing strange problem with Jenkins JaCoCo code report plugin. In case of build phase end with success plugin generates report, but if build phase failed because of failed tests, jacoco plugin is not executed at all in post-build.

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
-Djacoco.haltOnFailure=false
```

Comment: Hi Peter, 

but where should I put that option?

I have sample job with already generated jacoco binary exec file, and just need to do code report regardless build status. Here is the sample job: 

Build
Execute shell : exit 1

Post Build:
Record JaCoCo coverage report pointing to exec, class/src paths

Comment: haltOnFailure boolean 0.6.1 Halt the build if any of the checks fail. Seems this is not I need

Comment: You are using jacoco without maven?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are having a pipeline job.
If so, add `runAlways: false`, for example

```
post {
    always{
         jacoco(
            execPattern: '**/target/*.exec',
            classPattern: '**/target/classes/*',
            sourcePattern: '**/src/main',
            runAlways: true
        )
    }
}
```

Taken from https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/jacoco/